# clear all of document source with javascript

Tags: javascript, document

how to clear all of document text with java script ?
I tried this but this code clear only body element :

`document.body.innerHTML="";`

Comment: `document.write('');` is the fastest way to get rid of all code on a page (after the page has been parsed). But why would you need this?

Comment: document.write(''); dosen't work.

Comment: Then you call it during the page parsing, not after.

Comment: I can edit a post of a website.  so i want to change all of document source to my deface page :)

Comment: Why not just change the location?

Comment: i want to change the source ... is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use

`document.body.innerText =  '';`

to remove the entire page text